# Dynamically creating <DIV id's> in View AND JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm very new to javascript (like 98.9%), so apologies in advance if this is a dumb question...

I currently have a list of book titles, and I am trying to put a small graph next to each bulleted item in the list. So to generate the graph, I'm using flot, and setting it up to use a stacked bar chart, horizontally.

Now my list may be 2, may be 20 items long. It all depends on the user who is logged in.

The challenge I have is that flot seems to work on the basis that a specifically identified HTML  place holder must be set up for the graph, and then the javascript (external file in my case) which generates the graph, puts the resulting graphic into that specified placeholder.

If I've got more than one item, I need to dynamically create more unique  in both the View, and then also in the javascript.

I could probably do it by writing my embedding my javascript in the View, and using some PHP to create the  id's, but somehow that doesn't sound right - I'd rather try keep the neat seperation of unobtrusive JavaScript, View, Model, CSS etc.

Some pointers please...?

(This is PHP, CodeIgniter, JavaScript and CSS3)

[EDIT: Code example]

Below is not working code - it's "mid-experiment"

This is my JavaScript (in a separate myJS.js file)

```
function plotWithOptions(t,a,p) {

$(function () {
    var d1 = [[t,10]];
    var d2 = [[a,10]];
    var d3 = [[p,10]];

    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ d1, d2, d3 ], {
        series: {
            stack: 0,
            fill: true,
            linewidth: 1,
            bars: { show: true, barWidth: 10, horizontal: true}
        },
        xaxis: {max: 100, show:false},
        yaxis: {max: 100, show:false},
        grid: {show: false}
    });
});
}
```

This is my View (CodeIgniter)

```
<script src="/assets/myJS.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>    

<p>This book is rated....
<div id="placeholder1" style="width:300px;height:100px;"></div>
<script>    plotWithOptions(28,14,11); </script>

<p>This book is rated....
<div id="placeholder2" style="width:300px;height:100px;"></div>
<script>    plotWithOptions(28,27,1); </script>

<p>This book is rated....    
<div id="placeholder3" style="width:300px;height:100px;"></div>
<script>    plotWithOptions(28,27,26); </script>

<p>This book is rated....
<div id="placeholder4" style="width:300px;height:100px;"></div>
<script>    plotWithOptions(28,14,11); </script>
```

Comment: If you've got some code to do with what you've already tried, please do post it. It will help everyone out

Comment: Done... although it's not anything remotely working yet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution. I'm not sure if there is a "more correct" way of doing it, but the cost-benefit of finding a "purer/more elegant answer" is a beyond me right now.

This is the JavaScript file myGraphs.js

```
function plotWithOptions(n,t,a,p) {

$(function () {
    var d1 = [[t,10]];
    var d2 = [[a,10]];
    var d3 = [[p,10]];

    var divReference = "#placeholder"+n

    $.plot($(divReference), [ d1, d2, d3 ], {
        series: {
            stack: 0,
            fill: true,
            linewidth: 1,
            bars: { show: true, barWidth: 10, horizontal: true}
        },
        xaxis: {max: 100, show:false},
        yaxis: {max: 100, show:false},
        grid: {show: false}
    });
});
}
```

And this is my CodeIgniter View

```
<script src="/assets/myGraphs.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>    



<div id="Whatever">
    <ul>
        <?php
        for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
            echo "\n".'<li>';
            echo "\n".'<div id="placeholder'.$i.'" style="width:300px;height:20px;"></div>';
            echo "\n".'<script>plotWithOptions('.$i.',28,14,11); </script>';
            echo "\n".'</li>';
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```